# Uninitialized bytes in __interceptor_popen

Tags: c++

I have this function which gives me the default network interface and  I noted that when compiled with fsanitize flags it cause an error at runtime.

flags `-fsanitize=undefined  -fsanitize=memory`

Code

```
int execute(std::string cmd, std::string &output)
{
    const int bufsize = 128;
    std::array<char, bufsize> buffer;

    auto pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (!pipe)
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");

    size_t count;
    do
    {
        if ((count = fread(buffer.data(), 1, bufsize, pipe)) > 0)
        {
            output.insert(output.end(), std::begin(buffer), std::next(std::begin(buffer), count - 1));
        }
    } while (count > 0);

    return pclose(pipe);
}

std::string defaultInterface;
execute("ip r | awk '/^default/ {print $5}'", defaultInterface);
```

The error is,

```
Uninitialized bytes in __interceptor_popen at offset 34 inside [0x703000009ff0, 35)
==583286==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
```

The line which cause this is,

```
auto pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
```

But I don't see anything Uninitialized there. Is this a false positive?